# Adding a custom PivotField to PivotFields Collection

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have in my PivotTable PivotField("serialNo") ... This is a string.
I would like to add a custom PivotField("serialNoPrefix").
The value of "serialNoPrefix" is LEFT(serialNo, 5).

I'm doing this because I want to group the data by serialNoPrefix. I can't use CalculatedField because because I can't place it inside the Rows area.

My data source is an external Access db.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: you can't add a calculated column to the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Excel do you have? You can do this using either the PowerQuery add-in or the PowerPivot add-in, which are both free.

- If you’ve got Excel 2013 or later, you can write Measures using the
  DAX formula language that appear directly inside any fields appearing
  in the Values area of your PivotTables. These give you incredible
  control over how data is filtered and shaped before being aggregated.
- If you’ve got a premium version of Excel that includes the PowerPivot
  add-in, in addition to Measures you can also create something called
  Calculated Columns that give you similar control over fields that
  appear in other areas of your PivotTables (i.e. the areas shown below
  right.)
- If you’ve got Excel 2016 or later, you can also use a baked-in tool
  called PowerQuery to radically automate the process of shaping and
  feeding data from all manner of sources to these new PivotTables.
- If you don’t have the versions of Excel listed above, you can
  download add-ins from Microsoft that will install this advanced
  wizardry alongside your older version of Excel…although you might
  find that they don’t offer the exact same functionality as their
  baked-in counterparts in later versions. But what the heck…they’re
  *Ka-CHING* completely free, and much, much better than nothing.